# Extract substring from SQL Server column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, substring, patindex

I am trying to figure out how to extract a substring from a column in SQL Server. I very much would like to be able to do it directly in SQL if at all possible. The content of my column holds the responses of a web form and looks like this:

```
"a:27:{s:5:\"FieldX\";s:22:\"Response to FieldX\";s:16:\"WhatProductDoYouWant\";s:31:\"SomeProduct\";s:16:\"FieldY\";s:4:\"Response to FieldY\"}
```

In the previous example the form has three fields with their respective responses as:

```
FieldName                  Response
FieldX                     Response to FieldX
WhatProductDoYouWant       SomeProduct
FieldY                     Response to FieldY
```

I need to extract the answer to `WhatProductDoYouWant`, that is, I need `SomeProduct`.

Constraints:

- I do not know how many fields there are before or after the field I am looking for, it is a dynamic form.
- The answer to the field is dynamic, meaning I do not know how many characters I need to account for, it could be anything.

For a full example, let's say I have the following table in SQL Server table:

```
CREATE TABLE WebFormData 
(
    FormID int,
    Responses varchar(MAX)
);

INSERT INTO WebFormData (FormID, Responses)
VALUES (1, 'a:27:{s:5:\"FieldX\";s:22:\"Response to FieldX\";s:16:\"WhatProductDoYouWant\";s:31:\"SomeProduct\";s:16:\"FieldY\";s:4:\"Response to FieldY\"}');

INSERT INTO WebFormData (FormID, Responses)
VALUES (2, 'a:27:{s:5:\"FieldX\";s:22:\"Response to FieldX\";a:27:{s:7:\"FieldX2\";s:27:\"Response to FieldX2\";s:16:\"WhatProductDoYouWant\";s:31:\"SomeOtherProduct\";s:16:\"FieldZ\";s:4:\"Response to FieldZ\";s:16:\"FieldY\";s:4:\"Response to FieldY\"}');
```

I would like to have a SQL query like:

```
SELECT FormID, someExpression AS Products 
FROM WebFormData
```

And I would expect to have as results:

```
1, SomeProduct
2, SomeOtherProduct
```

I have been able to identify the index of the initial character I am looking for but I have no idea how to determine the length of the substring:

```
SELECT 
    FormID, 
    SUBSTRING(Responses, CHARINDEX('WhatProductDoYouWant', Responses) + 30, 20) AS Products
FROM 
    WebFormData
```

(The 20 in the length parameter of the substring function is just a random number for demonstration purposes)

The query returns:

```
FormID,Products
1, SomeProduct\";s:16:\
2, SomeOtherProduct\";s
```

Any help would be appreciated. Please let me know if clarification is required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply chain *cross apply* with a *values* clause to find your start and length positions, and use *nullif* to handle where the text does not exist:

```
select Substring(Responses, NullIf(p1,0) + 30, p2-(NullIf(p1,0) + 30)) Products
from WebFormData
cross apply (values(CHARINDEX('WhatProductDoYouWant', Responses)))x(p1) 
cross apply (values(CHARINDEX('\"', Responses, p1 + 30 )))y(p2);
```

Comment: Thanks @Stu!, that indeed works.  I must say I do not understand why, I am trying to wrap my head around it.   I have never used cross apply.

Comment: first ot chekc where the position is for WhatProductDoYouWant and store it in p1 second it looks for \ in the rest as you have both postion of the wanted result you can extract it the thirty are the lenght of your string

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps more than you are looking for.

If you want to parse the entire string

**Example**

```
;with cte as (
select FormID 
      ,B.RetSeq
      ,RetVal = replace(B.RetVal,'\"','')
      ,grp = sum(retSeq % 2) over (partition by FormID order by RetSEQ)
      ,col = retSeq % 2
 From WebFormData A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract-JSON](replace(Responses,'}',';'),':',';') B
)
Select FormID
      ,Seq      = Grp
      ,Question = max(case when col=1 then RetVal end)
      ,Response = max(case when col=0 then RetVal end)
  From cte
  Group By FormID,Grp
  Order By FormID,Grp
```

**Results**

[image]

**The Helper Function if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract-JSON] (@String nvarchar(max),@Delim1 nvarchar(100),@Delim2 nvarchar(100))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  

    Select RetSeq = row_number() over (order by RetSeq)
          ,RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex(@Delim2,RetVal)-1)
    From  (
            Select RetSeq = [Key]+1
                  ,RetVal = Value
             From  OpenJSON( N'["'+replace(string_escape(@String,'json'),@Delim1,'","')+N'"]' )

          ) C1
    Where charindex(@Delim2,RetVal)>1

)
```

[image]